# Why Ubuntu Server ask me to restart services?

Tags: apt, server, postgresql

I've installed latest Ubuntu Server on Linode. When I install some packages with `apt-get`, like node.js or postgres it stops and the window with question pops up.

How to disable this question window?

As it breaks my automated installation scripts. I don't understand what it asks and don't know and don't use the services listed in questions, I use only node.js and postgres to run some web server.

[image]

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do use those services. Most folks would be quite upset if those services stopped for a few days.

Some of those services may need to be briefly stopped in order to install the packages that you want installed.

You should indeed restart all four services: Select all four, then OK.

Reference: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/needrestart-for-servers/21552

Comment: Thanks. Seems like Ubuntu Server is harder and harder to use with every year, maybe indeed it's worth to take look at this Docker thing :)

Comment: The Ubuntu developers do not intend to lock you into a distro that you do not wish to use.

Comment: How to avoid this tip ?